# Laravel - How do i get the SUM of a column of a distinct product?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to do something in Laravel and i'm failing pretty hard.
Can someone help me with this?

This is what i am trying:

**Data i have**

```
Name - Quantity

Water:10
Water:20
Cola:5
Cola:10
```

**Results i want in the view**

```
Water:30
Cola:15
```

**This is what i have so far**

*Controller:*

```
public function total()
    {
        $orders = Order::latest('order_id')->get();
        $products = Product::distinct()->get('name'); 

        return view('home.total')->with('orders', $orders)->with('products', $products);
    }
```

*View:*

```
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        @forelse ($products as $product)
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{$product->name}}</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        {{$product->sum('quantity')}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @empty
        @endforelse
    </div>
```

This results in the products being distinct but the quantity is a SUM of the all quantities of all products instead of per product.

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `group by` product.

```
$products = App\Product::groupBy('name')
    ->select(\DB::raw("SUM(`quantity`) AS `quantity_sum`"), 'name')
    ->get();
```

It should give you the desired result with a set of rows containing `name` and `quantity_sum` fields.

That should help you.

Comment: GREAT! This is what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
$result = DB::select('SELECT sum(Quantity), name FROM products GROUP BY name');
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply.
I just tried this out and i get the follow error:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: SELECT distinct(name), sum(quantity) FROM products)

Comment: Hey, and do i send the $result with the view? If so, do i replace {{$product->sum('quantity')}} with $result?

Comment: please `dd($result)` and then you pass to view and decide how to display this value in your view

Comment: Oh, i already did that but i didn't really understand what was happening.
Because i only get a quantity but not a name. I would like to display the name of the prod and quantity.
0 => {#330 ▼
    +"sum(Quantity)": "5"